# "Dead simple.." vs. "Really simple.."

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives

I'm writing copy for a new web application and I'm having some trouble with it.

On one headline I've written "It's dead simple ...", but while my client was reviewing it he asked if this is not too 'cool', and suggested "It's really simple ...".

The context is: Web 2.0 application, really COOL with a beautiful bright homepage design!

How can I convince him to use "Dead simple...", or am I wrong and "Really simple..." is better?

Comment: *Dead simple* is an idiom and idioms can be great or horrible for your business communication. It depends on your audience (if they understand them or not). On average it is better to play it safe and use a widely understood term and more formal language (but again if you are trying to appeal to audience that like that term you might keep it).

Comment: If you don't use *dead simple*, I'd suggest going with just "It's simple!" – *really* adds very little intensity, and then the ellipsis saps it all away.

Comment: The question's not answerable. It depends on the audience. If you decide against *dead*, other common collocates in descending order of frequency are: *this, (just) so, too, beyond, surprisingly, elegantly,* and *remarkably*. http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=13532291

Comment: Might there be users speaking English only as second language?  And might they fail to understand "dead simple"?

Comment: @Unreason: I'm not sure *dead simple* is really an "idiom" as such. It's just that in common usage, *dead* frequently means "very". It's often used with *easy, right, straight,* and several other adjectives.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I do agree that dictionaries will list *dead* as intensifier, and you can say that then it does not contradict the principle of compositionality, ergo it is not an "idiom". However, I think it is an idiom since it is typical to English language and it works as intensifier only for certain adjectives/phrases.

Comment: @Unreason: Yes, I wouldn't want to overstate my case there. It's just that, to me at least, an "archetypal" idiomatic usage is one where you've got little chance of understanding it from established definitions of the component words. And as you say, many dictionaries will give that "intensifier" sense for "dead" - which is all you need to know to understand the usage.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/34651/11762

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Dead simple* is very informal. Whether or not you use it in preference to *really simple* depends entirely on the impression you want to make on your readers.

Answer (score 3):

The "Dead" adds strong emphasis, and any reader who does *not* find it simple will think you arrogant, assumptive, or both. I'd avoid it. Just plain "Simple" would be my choice.

What you find simple others may not. You are walking a line between encouraging your audience to continue without fear of complexity, and not sounding like what may rocket science to them is merely falling off a log to you.

Comment: I agree with this. While you may be making a point, why not let the application speak for itself? The chances are that many people will not find it dead simple. The user can decide if they think it's "simple." Why not just describe what the app does, how it is intended to work,  and how it may benefit them? I would hope that using an app would be enjoyable much more than "easy to use." If it's not easy to use, then that should be sorted out. Not only does "dead simple" make it seem like it's for dummies, it also makes the app sound, well - "simple." PS "falling off a log" = great.