# Why does 'dead on' mean 'very accurate'?

Tags: etymology, phrases, expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does the phrase “dead simple” originate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51593/where-does-the-phrase-dead-simple-originate)

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dead_on), the phrase 'dead on' means 'very accurate' or 'exactly at'. This is also how I have used the phrase.

But why? What's the connection there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dead):

> Used from 16c. in adjectival sense of "utter, absolute, quite" (cf. *dead drunk* first attested 1590s; dead heat, 1796). As an adverb, from late 14c. *Dead on* is 1889, from marksmanship.

I'm sure that someone with OED access can provide a complete answer with some citations.

If you consider someone shooting *on a mark* (at a target), then *dead on* could be considered an elision of *dead on the mark*. In other words, completely on target. A similar expression would be *dead on the money*.

According to one online [source](http://askville.amazon.com/Whatt-origin-expression-money/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=13856391):

> For prize competitions in [sic] a coin would be set at the middle of the target and the archer whose arrow landed closest to the coin would take the coin as the prize.
>   
>   Therefore right on the money would mean the center of the target (dead center).
>   
>   Practice of shooting the coin with arrows is still used today.
>   
> [[Link to archery event where coins are shot at](http://www.mac.asn.au/news_7.htm)]
>   
>   DERIVATION: This expression derives from an old English sport, bullbaiting dogs try to pull a bull by his nose to the ground. Gamblers would place a bet "on the bull's eye" if he wished to make a bet. Crowns, an English coin, were used to bet so frequently "on the bull's eye" that the coin itself came to be called a bull's-eye. Later, the term was applied to the black center of a target. The idiom *right on the money* is also derived from the ancient interchangeable use of a coin, bull's-eye and the center of a target.

A few more details about the word *dead* in this and similar phrases is found in [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/51593/24117).

Comment: +1 Depending on the distance to the target, you might aim your sights _high_ (target is further than the rifle's optimum range), aim _low_ (target is closer than optimum), or aim _dead on_ the target or _dead centre_ (target is at optimum).

Comment: Cool! And I guess the use of 'dead' for 'absolute' might be because 'dead' is quite 'absolute'. You're either dead or you're not. Makes total sense :)