# Examples of using "dead" to mean directly

Tags: phrases

I'm looking for more examples that use "dead" to mean directly. Some I already have include:

1.) "It's dead ahead. You can't miss it."
2.) I looked him dead in the eye.

Or perhaps to mean exact/exactly:

3.) "Dead on! Absolutely correct!"
4.) This town is the dead center of the country.

Comment: Something like "That cemetery is the dead centre of town"?

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Comment: Asking for a list of examples is generally off-topic here. You can make requests for words, but they need to fit a specific context, so that we can come up with a single, good answer. Asking about the etymology of this sense of *dead* would also be on topic (and interesting).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about creating a list of examples, which is off-topic on this site.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91343/why-does-dead-on-mean-very-accurate

Comment: adverb [often as submodifier] **1** Absolutely; completely: *you’re dead right he was dead against the idea* (;) Synonyms **1.1** Exactly: *they arrived dead on time* **1.2** Straight; directly: *red flares were seen dead ahead* Synonyms **1.3** British • informal Very: *omelettes are dead easy to prepare* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dead

Comment: You can Google for more and improve the post. See also: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dead

Comment: 'A dead loss' used to be (50 years ago) quite common in at least the NW of England, for 'a complete waste of time' (usually referring to a man). 'Dead in the centre / the dead centre' show/s the related prepositional phrase-modifying and noun-associating (though I'd argue not exactly adjectival) usages. 'Sailed dead ahead' and 'hit it dead centre' illustrate the adverbial-modifier usage. Dead right/wrong; dead still; dead stupid/thick; dead clever; dead rich/poor are examples I've come across. The perceived degree of slanginess seems to differ with the particular collocation.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, neither *directly* nor *exactly* really captures the meaning here.  It's more of an intensifier, as in *dead last* and *dead of winter*, something along the lines of *most* or *ultimate.*

Answer (score 0):

The nautical `dead slow`, basically meaning as slow as possible while maintaining a straight course.

Answer (score 0):

Another example is [dead reckoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning),

> the process of calculating one's current position by using a previously determined position, or fix.

Which may not actually fit your "directly" criteria, but [dead to rights](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dead+to+rights) seems to -

> in the act; (guilty) without question.

The "without question" *being* "direct".

Answer (score -1):

The intensifier *dead* generally means [exactly] straight to me.

In baseball you can hit a ball to dead center field.

In golf you have dead to the hole.