# Why is something "dead" straight?

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context

What relevance has the word "dead" to being "straight"?

It should be noted that any adjective would form a tautology, since something is either *straight* or it's *not* straight (there is no possible qualification).

That notwithstanding, the addition of "dead" is used to *emphasize*, or rather *confirm*, that the object being described is in fact straight.

But why "dead"?

---

Usage examples:

> The road between here and the next town is dead straight
>   That piece of steel is dead straight
>   You must draw the line dead straight for the geometry to work

Comment: Can you add an example sentence. I think I know what you mean, but maybe I don't.

Comment: @developerwjk examples added. In usage context, "dead" takes a meaning like "exactly" or "precisely"

Comment: Dictionaries show that the adjective _dead_ and the intensifier _dead_ are intercategorial polysemes (ie they're not homonyms). Etymon gives the first known use of the intensifier usage, but, apart from mentioning the associations of dead / drunk / dead drunk, it doesn't explain the etymological branching.

Comment: @Bohemian By your definition, there is no such thing as a *straight* road in the world. After all, the surface of the planet is curved. Almost every supposedly absolute adjective can be graded to indicate degree or approximation; thus, something can be *more perpendicular* and someone can be *more pregnant*, to use two common examples.

Comment: @choster It is true that few things are actually "straight". It is possible that some (short) roads are literally straight. Nevertheless, we all know what "straight" means, and I was just making a point of fact. It would be reasonable to consider a road "straight" if the projection onto a plane tangential to any point on that road is straight. Feel free to edit out that paragraph if you feel it makes the question more clear.

Comment: You never heard "dead ahead"?

Comment: [This comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125910/when-and-how-did-pretty-enter-english-as-an-intensifying-adverb#comment259689_125910) explains 'dead' quite nicely.

Answer (score 4):

The role of "dead" in your usage examples is similar to the role of "dead" in the phrase "dead simple", which is the subject of this question:

[Where does the phrase “dead simple” originate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51593/where-does-the-phrase-dead-simple-originate)

The answer provides a definition of "dead" from [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dead)

> Used from 16c. in adjectival sense of "utter, absolute, quite" (as in dead drunk, first attested 1590s; dead heat, 1796).

as well as some interesting suggestions for how the phrase came into being.

Comment: You might want to mention that it is used more frequently in the UK and in the North of England more specifically.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: I didn't know that. I assumed it was universal. Certainly it's widely used in Ireland, and a quick Google search indicates plenty of usage in the US and Australia too.

Comment: Yep, this answer is *dead on* (as described as http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dead-on )